# Unable to add condition

Tags: flow

How do I add condition in my MS Flow?I was always able to do that. It is only showing 2 options to add actions. Is there any change in UI. I am nowhere finding option to add condition. 
How do I add condition in my MS Flow?I was always able to do that. 
[image: my flow screeshot]

Answer (score 3):

You now add a condition the same way you add an action.

[image: Add a condition]